# Java regex for 12 hour time validation involving a semi colon

Tags: java, regex, time

Im trying to make a regex expression to fulfill the criteria of being a time in am or pm.

I have tried  `time.matches("[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}")` but no matter what time I enter I cannot get it to match, for example 20:00 does not match.
Also how would I add matching AM or PM at the end (lower or upper case accepted).

Would it being something like this `time.matches("[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}[am|pm]")`

Comment: `[am|pm]` should be `(?:am|pm)`. Also, please post reproducible code.

Comment: @Henry oh woops mb, tired as :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For validating a 12 hour time format your regular expression should be

`(1[012]|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9](\\s)?(?i)(am|pm)`

`1[012]` -> 1 followed by 0 1 or 2 because only 10,11,12 are allowed times

or

`[1-9]` -> any single digit time from 1 to 9

followed by a semi colon

`[0-5][0-9]` -> for validating minutes. Anything from 00 to 59 is accepted.

`(\\s)?` ignores any white space between the time and AM or PM

`(?i)(am|pm)` case insensitive am,pm validation

Comment: The brackets around `\\s` are unnecessary, but +1

Comment: Thanks for the explanation too!

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}([a|p]m)?",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher match = p.matcher("20:00PM");
    if (match.find())
         System.out.println(true);
     else
         System.out.println(false);
```

You can use other pattern as below:
 "^\d\d:\d\d([a|p]m)?"